# Is there a way to have an Excel Table range expand based on the expansion of another Table?

Tags: excel, dynamic, pivot-table, powerquery

I'm using Excel 365

I have a fairly big simulation model that calculates a number of metrics into the future for an education system. The model has a **Table** (with a capital T, the kind that you declare in the Insert tab) for *Targets*, another for *Current and historical data*, and a number of **Tables** that use these two to make the projections into the future.

Each line in this simulation model is related to a State within a country, and every table starts (column A) with the name of this State. The columns are then different variables that are either taken from the *Targets* **Table**, from the *Current and historical data* **Table**, or the result of the different calculations using these two.

[image: Current configuration]

I'm interested in expanding this model from each line being a State, to each line being a Municipality. The equations and the overall logic remains the same, but the number of lines will increase considerably.

[image: New configuration]

Is there a way for all the projection **Tables** to expand downwards to accommodate the increased number of rows in the *Targets* and *Current and historical data* **Tables**? For me the idea would be that once the user (not me) adds the additional lines in these two Tables (the two to the left), that the projection Tables in the other spreadsheets automatically expand to cover these new lines (the two on the right).

[image: Desired result]

I would need a no-VBA solution, since the idea is for this file to be used by people in different countries, using different versions of Excel, different operating systems, and different levels of skill, so I can't have the file break.

I tried using an OFFSET function with a COUNTA function for the height of the range, but while it accepts this when declaring the Table the first time, it becomes static and doesn't update when the number of rows.

I also tried to ingest the first two **Tables** within Power Query and then add them at the beginning of the **Tables** with projections using a Pivot Table in tabular form that repeats all labels (so that it shows the exact same thing as the original table, but the problem here is that when the PV expands the **Table** with the projection equations doesn't.

Comment: Have you attempted Dax in Power Pivot?
Have you attempted "replicating" the equations in Power Query instead of Excel Formulas?

Comment: Instead of using tables for the projections, could you hard code `INDEX()` for a large range that would cover the rows in the other two tables? Reference table rows that aren't populated yet and suppress errors with `IFERROR()`. Use conditional formatting for shading instead of formatting as tables.